# Problem in batch processing data with angular bracket

Tags: development, sharepoint-server

Trying to insert some data into multiline of text SharePoint field using batch processing. It was working fine if it doesn't have any words within <> angular bracket. If it has any words inside the angular bracket then it throws exception. If I try HTML encoding it doesn't display the word which was inside the angular bracket.

```
<Method ID="2">
    <SetList>LIST ID</SetList>
    <SetVar Name="Cmd">Save</SetVar>
    <SetVar Name="ID">New</SetVar>
    <SetVar Name="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office#Title">cde</SetVar>
    <SetVar Name="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office#Cmt">kjasdh <UserName> sadkfjhaskdjf</SetVar>
</Method>
```

The above lines are framed for the batch processing.

I need `kjasdh <UserName> sadkfjhaskdjf`. This line has to save in the multiline of text using batch processing.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem by adding one space after "<" and before ">".
 
Now I could able to get the out put like < UserName >.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the windows escape character "^" for the brackets.  So when you have

```
"kjasdh <UserName> sadkfjhaskdjf"
```

you should instead write

```
"kjasdh ^<UserName^> sadkfjhaskdjf"
```

Comment: <SetVar Name=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office#Cmt\">kjasdh ^<UserName^> sadkfjhaskdjf</SetVar> this was thrown exception